# eclipse plugin how to open file in IDE by code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am working on eclipse plugin in which i have to open a file from project explorer. 
Suppose i have a project ABC in project explorer. after right click on project i got a option to run my plugin tool. after processing i got some result like Check file xyz.java.

Now i want to open this file in IDE by code

i am using this

```
File absolute = new File("/Decider.java");  
File file = new File("/Decider.java");
IFileStore fileOnLocalDisk = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(absolute.toURI() );

FileStoreEditorInput editorInput = new FileStoreEditorInput(fileOnLocalDisk);

IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();

 try {  
    page.openEditor(editorInput, "org.eclipse.ui.DefaultTextEditor");         

    page.openEditor(editorInput, "MyEditor.editor");          

        IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(absolute.toURI() );
        IDE.openEditorOnFileStore( page, fileStore );

      } catch (PartInitException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    try {
        System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    IPath path = new Path(" /DirectoryReader.java");
    IFile sampleFile =  ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(path);

    IEditorInput editorInput1 = new FileEditorInput(sampleFile);
    IWorkbenchWindow window1=PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    IWorkbenchPage page1 = window1.getActivePage();
    try {
        page1.openEditor(editorInput1, "org.eclipse.ui.DefaultTextEdtior");
    } catch (PartInitException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

here it's create a new file named decider in c drive which means it's getting a wrong path.

but when i use path code in some independent java file as a normal **JAVA** project it's getting the correct path.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking. Do you just want to open the default editor on a project file, or a specific editor or what?

Comment: just want to open default eclipse editor as mention in code which is "org.eclipse.ui.DefaultTextEditor"

Comment: This problen is like when i run the plugin it's shows some error in a view like console of eclipse. Right now i want to open file which have bug.we have file name as you can see in absolute  variable. i want to open this file but by above code it's creating a new file in new location.

Comment: and this is eclipse editor for development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a file in the workspace you should use `IFile`. If you have a selection from Project Explorer or another view that should already be an `IFile` or can be adapted to an `IFile`.

If you just have a workspace relative path use `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(path)` (path would include a project).

To open the default editor for the file contents use

```
IDE.openEditor(page, file, true);
```

to open a specific editor use

```
IDE.openEditor(page, file, "editor id");
```

IDE is org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.

Comment: @KrzyH In general, no, you can't open an editor at a specific line - some editors don't even have the concept of a line. `IDE.openEditor` does return the `IEditorPart` that was opened, editors which implement `ITextEditor` have a `selectAndReveal` method which shows an offset in the file.